# If there is a function $H(e^{j\omega})$. Then will its conjugate be $H(e^{-j\omega})$?Why?

Tags: dft

If there is a function $H(e^{j\omega})$. Then will its conjugate be $H(e^{-j\omega})$?Why?

Let there be a function

$$H(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{1+ae^{-j\omega}}{1+\alpha e^{-j\omega}+\beta e^{-j2\omega}}$$

Then will its conjugate be:

$$H^*(e^{j\omega}) = \frac{1+ae^{+j\omega}}{1+\alpha e^{+j\omega}+\beta e^{+j2\omega}}$$

Where $j$ is an imaginary number equal to $\sqrt {-1}$.

How is it valid for the general case?

Comment: $j$ better be purely imaginary.

Comment: You are assuming, without explicitly saying so, that $a, \alpha, \beta$ are _real numbers_, else you would need to be conjugating them too.  The simplest way to get to the result that $H^*(e^{j\omega}) = H(e^{-j\omega})$ is to take the expression for $H(e^{j\omega})$ and wherever you find an $e^{j\omega}$ replace it with $e^{-j\omega}$ (and vice versa). Then compare the result to $H^*(e^{j\omega})$. Are they the same? Can you see why this shenanigan will not work if any of the coefficients (e.g. $a, \alpha, \beta$ in this instance) are complex-valued?

Answer (score 1):

What you say only holds true for real signals. Let's prove it by the definition of Fourier transform:

$$
H(e^{j\omega}) = \mathcal{F}[h(t)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t) e^{-j\omega t} dt
$$

and $H^*(e^{j\omega})$ should be

$$
H^*(e^{j\omega}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h^*(t) e^{j\omega t} dt
$$

thus

$$
H^*(e^{-j\omega}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h^*(t) e^{-j\omega t} dt = \mathcal{F}[h^*(t)] 
$$

If $h(n)$ is real, $\mathcal{F}[h^*(t)] = \mathcal{F}[h(t)] $, we can derive that

$$
H^*(e^{-j\omega}) = H(e^{j\omega}) 
$$

Take conjungate on both sides of the equation above, we have

$$
H(e^{-j\omega}) = H^*(e^{j\omega}) 
$$

Comment: @DilipSarwate Oh sorry, my fault. Edited.